Amount of space I am using by using df command
I am trying to figure out how much space I am using by using df -h command as below
root@bi:~# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              3.2G  1.5M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   48G   42G  3.9G  92% /
tmpfs                               16G   24K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  254M  1.6G  14% /boot
tmpfs                              3.2G  4.0K  3.2G   1% /run/user/0
overlay                             48G   42G  3.9G  92% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/37b5a9553a5f222c0ec024595d9b1df60ce4e903a8e9cd6d97c2ccf813bc810a/merged

I have one question in regards to above since I can't understand the entry for "overlays" as it is using the same amount of space like "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", both using 42G
Are the overlay and /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv in two seprate locations?


Are the overlay and /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv in two seprate locations?

They're on the same physical device in your case. They don't have to be, however. Thus the same space. Here's what Docker writes about it:

OverlayFS layers two directories on a single Linux host and presents them as a single directory. These directories are called layers, and the unification process is referred to as a union mount. OverlayFS refers to the lower directory as lowerdir and the upper directory a upperdir. The unified view is exposed through its own directory called merged.

Docker images are built up of layers, and these layers are merged using OverlayFS, which merges different directories to a single view.


Are the overlay and /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv in two seprate locations?

Not necessarily, but df is not aware of such relationships.
Overlayfs is a "pass-through" filesystem which reports the information from its lower directory, but df doesn't know that – it doesn't have special knowledge of how overlayfs behaves – so it just shows each mounted filesystem in turn, even if that results in duplicate entries.
(And indeed an overlayfs could be mounted within one subtree but with its lower dirs taken from another, at which point "Does the admin want to see this?" gets increasingly complex to decide.)
Use df -T to show the filesystem type field, which will let you more quickly determine which entries are worth paying attention to. If you want to hide less-useful entries from the list, either point df to a specific filesystem such as df -h /home or do something like this with the -x (exclude type) option:
alias dff="df -xtmpfs -xdevtmpfs -xoverlayfs -xrootfs -xecryptfs -xafs"

(You'll need this in the future when you get a more recent version of systemd, which in its infinite wisdom has started creating dozens of tiny tmpfs instances under /run…)

In most environments this is hidden. I don't know why it's visible here.
You can find useful info here

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, please provide context around links so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. If possible summarise or quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.  (I didn't vote down, but often link-only answers attract downvotes)
